# Need a SMTP test server for integration tests (selenium)

Tags: java, email, selenium

I've got the following scenario:

An application is being functional-tested using selenium. One action performed on the interface results in sending an email to a particular address, which can be manually set to some value. It works fine. And now, I'd like my selenium tests to check for that email. How to achieve this without having to use real server? I mean this has to be a real server but it has to listen on localhost and start from java. I don't think tools like *dumbster* or *greenmail* fits in here, do they? From what I have read in the documentation they are not accessible outside the running application.

Is there such tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Since it is only for testing purposes, set up a library that stores the emails in the database during testing, and actually emails them in development.

Comment: Do I have to setup a special database for that? There is no real lightweight smtp server which I could just host locally to intercept messages sent by the application from the testing scope?

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is no "quality of service" guarantees for SMTP delivery, a functional test for an app just needs to prove that a valid SMTP message is accepted by a remote MTA -- or is accepted after an eventual retry. Once accepted by the MTA, the app has no more control over how long, or even if, it will or can be delivered to a store where it can be fetched or read by a MUA.

That is, the most important part of this test is the check of the MTA SMTP response. Many, but not all, 5xx responses might be considered an app failure. Likewise, most 2xx responses might be a success. 4xx codes would have to be considered either way. The various ways various MTAs could respond to a message is many and varied. Not to mention that some codes are part of the mail transfer chat where the app might have to retry later; this is technically not an error except after some number of retries over some number of hours.

Functional or release testing may better include sending test messages to more than one type of MTA, as the SMTP standard is implemented in odd ways across MTAs, and an SMTP powered app might have to take those 
idiosyncrasies into account, rather than prove that some message actually made it to a mailbox.

While you could use a small SMTP server to dump received emails into files that your test framework would check to make sure are present and "correct" the devil would be in the details regarding exactly how these messages were presented to the test -- you end up having to not only implement a MTA chat in the app and test framework, but also a little MUA part to validate the message based on some criteria. I'm not a fan of this, given you wouldn't really be testing the app anyway. Rather, you'd be testing the MTA and the testing support code!